# Primitive element in $\mathbb{F}_9$, constructed with $f(t)=t^2 + 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, field-theory

Given $f(t) = t^2 + 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_9$, I first showed that $f(t)$ is irreducible over this field. $f(t)$ is not a primitive polynomial because $t^8 \ne 1$. So now I'm trying to find a primitive element $\alpha$ of $\mathbb{F}_9$.

$\mathbb{F}_9 = \{0,1,-1,t,t+1,t-1,-t,-t+1,-t-1 \}$. I know that I have to find a non-zero element in this set with order $8$ ($=9-1$). It's clear that $1,-1,t,-t$ cannot be primitive elements of $\mathbb{F}_9$. Let's look at the other four elements:

$(t+1)^8 = ((t+1)^2)^3 = (2t)^3=-t^3 = t;$

$(t-1)^8 = \dots= -t;$

$(-t+1)^8 = \dots = -t;$

$(-t-1)^8 = \dots = t;$

Does this mean that there are no elements of order $8$ and therefor no primitive elements in $\mathbb{F}_9$?

Comment: A booboo with the exponents: $(t+1)^8=((t+1)^2)^4$ because $2\cdot4=8$. But $2\cdot3=6$ only.

Comment: Anyway, $\Bbb{F}_9^*$ is cyclic of order eight, and you listed all the elements of order four or lower.

Comment: Check again $\pm1\pm t$ are all of order eight.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1703782/11619). (looking for a better duplicate target...)